# VBScript find text in HTML

Tags: php, html, vbscript

I am trying to use VBS to gather names of files from a website. I can get the HTML code but I don't know how to extract the name. I haven't yet found anything that can do what I need. I need to extract the name of a file from a table. The HTML around what I need looks  like this `tsc_details.php?show_id=`**NEEDED INFO**`">` There are many different names formatted this same way and the number of names will vary from time to time.

NOTE: There will be multiple of these at various places in the HTML code.

Here is my code

```
On Error Resume Next
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "WWW.Webpage.com"
ie.Visible = True
While IE.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
ie.document.getElementById("f_user").Value = "user"
ie.document.getElementById("f_pass").Value = "pass"
ie.document.All.Item("submitb").Click
While IE.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
```

This is all of the code I have. It works perfectly for logging in to the page I just don't know how to get the Information I need.

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried so far? Where is your code? Please read what a [mcve] is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out and wanted to share my findings in case it helped someone out.

```
For Each a In IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")
  If InStr(a.GetAttribute("href"),"tsc_details.php?show_id=") > 0 Then
var = a.GetAttribute("href")
var = Replace(var,"tsc_details.php?show_id=","")     
exit for
end if
next
```

Used this code

Comment: You are supposed to come back a day later and mark your answer as the answer.